# QGIS composer - How can I eliminate striping across transparent raster layers?

Tags: raster, qgis

I have downloaded QGIS dev version 1.7.0-114 and I have come across some weird behaviour in the composer.

I create a map with a hillshade and a transparent DEM ontop of it, pretty standard stuff. When I export this map to an image format I get two strips across my output, this happens for a number of formats (png, jpg, bmp, tiff) and the stripes seem to be in the same place everytime. I have attached an example below (sorry for the size of the attachment).

[image]

The stripes appear in the same position on the page every time and this happens with different raster datasets, so I have ruled out the data.

Also depending on the page size you may get 1 stripe (A5 as shown above), 2 stripes (A4) or no strips (custom dimensions h100 x w100).

Is this something that can be overcome via some settings which I may have overlooked? Or might this be something funny in the software?

Comment: not a QGIS guy but at a first glance this appears to be a video card/driver issue. does this happen on a different computer? update drivers and try again, just a thought. (have similar issues with exporting to image in other software and it is video card related)

Comment: hmmm that is strange.  I have never seen that happen before.  I'll try and replicate on my machine.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, let me know how you go. I went home at lunch time and tried on my lappie (running Ubunutu 10.10) and it worked fine. Wonder if its the video card related like Jakub mentioned or a Windows related?

Comment: Should be fixed in next release or go to trunk - http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5133

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This same question came across the QGIS user email list last week.
http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2011-April/011691.html

> Any idea, why a narrow band appears after saving/exporting from print
> composer?
>
> http://www.flickr.com/photos/61556126@N07/5602729271/
>
> http://www.flickr.com/photos/61556126@N07/5602729269/

it was logged about a month ago @ http://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/ticket/3640

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I wonder why this isn't happening on my Ubuntu install? I have only experienced this on my work machine which runs windows 7.