# Unattractive image artefact when exporting from QGIS's Print Composer

Tags: qgis, raster

When I export my map from Print Composer in QGIS 1.7.4, an odd red band appears across the middle of the image. This happens when I export to both PNG and PDF. Its not visible on the screen before export, or present in the original raster image.[image: Images showing red band across the middle]
The band is to the left of the island halfway down the coast, below Pwani.

Any ideas what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the source data? Is it possible you have two maps that overlap in that location?

Comment: It looks like the same bug logged in the answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8572/qgis-composer-how-can-i-eliminate-striping-across-transparent-raster-layers?rq=1

Comment: The base images is from NASA's Blue Marble, and is a single image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a composition, although my banding wasn't nearly as wide as yours appears to be. My banding was more of a streaking and was only in the output and not apparent on the screen.

I was able to correct for my problem by down sampling the quality (resolution) of my composition to 300 dpi (more than adequate for 24" x 36" output) in the composer > general settings. I haven't had a problem since and have concluded that a higher resolution setting might have exceeded my computers capability?

[image: settings]

Comment: I'll try this too, thanks. Will post results when I do.

Comment: Changing the DPI from 300 to 200 or 250 removed the band, but changing up from 300 to 400/500/600 did not.

Comment: + 1, apparently will be sorted when 1.9 is released or if you go to trunk. http://hub.qgis.org/issues/5133

Answer (score 6):

This seems to happen when you use a semi-transparent raster layer. Look at this

[QGIS composer - How can I eliminate striping across transparent raster layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8572/qgis-composer-how-can-i-eliminate-striping-across-transparent-raster-layers)

which describes exactly the same problem. It seems to be a bug, and as far as I know It has not been solved in 1.8 (tried in ubuntu and win7). So, the solution, is avoiding the use of semi-transparent raster in your composition. If you have a shaded relief model with no transparency, everything should be fine, no striping.

Comment: Yes, now you mention it, I think this happened after I made the base image a little transparent to lighten it.

Answer (score 0):

I also think it is a bug. For me it happens in QGIS 1.8.0 exactly everytime on the middle line of the page.

Here's how I circumvent the bug:

- open the PDF export in Illustrator
- Object > Reduce Transparency > Fine
- alternatively one can crop one of the two overlapping layers to avoid overlapping.