# Creating small globe locator map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, cartography

I've tried searching on gis.stackexchange and elsewhere but can't seem to figure this one out though it seems simple enough.

The type of locator I'm thinking of is similar to the one from the map in this post: [Unattractive image artefact when exporting from QGIS's Print Composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29872/unattractive-image-artefact-when-exporting-from-qgiss-print-composer)

[image]

Does anyone know of a tutorial out there?

Comment: It looks like the globe was Photoshop'd and added to the composer as an image object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use GMT to create the globe:

```
pscoast -JA0/20/2.5i -Bg30/g15 -Dl -A2000 -G187/142/46 -S109/202/255 \
-R0/360/-90/90 -P -N1 > simple_hemi.eps
```

You could then add it to your map composition as an image. See this post for an explanation: http://geospatialdesktop.com/2008/02/simple_globe/

Comment: thankfully there are homebrew formulas for installing netCDF and GMT. Excited about learning this new tool, and the script worked: http://i.imgur.com/AAzA7Nv.png

Answer (score 6):

There is an easier way to do this in QGIS. You can add a map to your layout that will serve as the "globe" locator map, and set the projection of this map to "Azimuthal Orthographic," more commonly called "Earth from Space."

The only complication is that you have to add the projection (centered where you like) via `Settings > Custom Projections`.

[This blog](http://www.statsmapsnpix.com/2019/09/globe-projections-and-insets-in-qgis.html) has a clear, step-by-step howto. The gist, add a new custom projection with the following definition

> +proj=ortho +lat_0=42.5 +lon_0=-0.5 +x_0=0 > +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs

and replace the values for `lat_0` and `lon_0` with the location the globe should be centered under.